# Equation of vectors with booleans in python

Tags: python, vector, boolean, equation

I am trying to create an equation where you input an array or vector and it includes a boolean function. For the items in the array where this is satisfied (bool=True), then the equation proceeds to be solved in one way to produce another array.

I have attached here the similar code that works in R and want to do something similar in python

```
a <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)

a-b+5*(a==0|b==0)
```

The output of that is a vector:

[1] 4 0 0 1 1 2

Does anyone know how to do something similar in python3, maybe with numpy?

Comment: Dont tag R if you are interested in a python answer, even though you may show an R example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(6)
b = np.repeat(np.arange(1,4),2)
a-b+5*(np.equal(a,0) | np.equal(b,0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([1,1,2,2,3,3])
a-b+5*((a==0)|(b==0))
#> array([4, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots and lots of ways.
Here's one:

```
a = range(6)
b = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
r = [ai - bi + 5*(ai==0 or bi==0) for ai, bi in zip(a,b)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!